# Do child trigger runs parent trigger also?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameObject whose hierarchy contains

1. **parent** contains `box collider`, `kinematic rigidbody` and `script` that
   contains `OnTriggerEnter` event.
2. Parent's first child contains box collider
3. Parent's first child of a child contains `box collider` and script contains `OnTriggerEnter`
4. Parent's first child of seconds child contains box collider and script contains `OnTriggerEnter`
   My simple question is do child trigger will run parent trigger also I have did it. it seems true and surprising!

Comment: How you have constructed your parent  - child relation? Share code with us to get help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They do **if** the child does not have a (kinematic) rigidbody. In this case the collider of the parent basically is the sum of all colliders of itself and it's childs (compound collider).

If you want them to behave individually, they need their own kinematic rigidbodys. Make sure they ignore each other in the OnTrigger though (e.g. via tag).

Comment: Yes, it's quite confusing. As Gunnar says, **IF** you just have the one rigidbody, which you should, "the" collider is the "sum" of all colliders.  Recall too that really it is very bizarre to have rigidbodys as the child of rigidbodys. You can do it but it is weird stuff.

Comment: it is much confusing concept! will it add some performance drawbacks if i use rigidbody to child also?

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan I don't know that, but it might cause weird behaviour for the child when you move the parent, at least for normal rigidbodys, I'm not sure about kinematic ones. For normal rigidbodys it is recommended to use joints to connect them as far as I know.

Comment: You made my day (and the day before that, since this problem was bugging me since then), thank you!

Comment: This answer solved my problem. 
I had a parent with a Rigid Body and its child with only one Box Collider. The parent was executing a function two times in a row (Unwanted behaviour) because he apparently collided 'two times'. The second collision was from the child's Box Collider.
So, yes, parents take into account the box colliders of their children (Like real ones do) and to fix that, I put a Rigid Body (Growing up/Moving out) with Kinematic on on that child.
But I have to admit that I noticed an FPS drop.